# loop with set interval inside

Tags: jquery, loops, setinterval

I need to write a text one by one letter, with pausing 3 sec. between.

I tried this but doesn't work. After 3 sec. entire text is written at once.

```
function thanks() {   
    $("#writer").text("");
    var txt = "Thanks for visiting !";

    for ( var i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
      setInterval(function(){
        var type = txt.substring(0, i);
        $("#writer").text(type);
      }, 3000);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're queuing up 22 calls at once, all happening 3 seconds later. Just create your interval once, outputting new text on each call. Stop the interval when you've run out of text.

```
function thanks() {   
  $("#writer").text("");
  var txt = "Thanks for visiting !";
  var i = 0;

  var int = setInterval( function() 
  {
    ++i;
    if (i > txt.length)
    {
      clearInterval(int);
      return;
    }

    var type = txt.substring(0, i);
    $('#writer').text(type);
  }, 3000);
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/AwLfx

Comment: +1 Also a good way to do it -- better, really, as it avoids creating lots of unnecessary functions. (Looks really alien to see a variable called `int` if you work in multiple languages, but of course it's perfectly valid here...)

Answer (score 1):

This is the classic closure problem, each function you're passing into `setInterval` has an *enduring reference* to `i`, not a copy of it, and so sees the same value of `i` (the value it has after the loop) when it runs. You also don't want to use `setInterval` here, you want `setTimeout`.

The usual answer is to have the function close over something else. These days that's really easy, you use [`Function#bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5), which was added in ES5 but can be correctly shimmed for older JS engines.

But in addition to that, we also have something else to fix: We need to give each function a different delay, we can't use 3000 for all of them, or they'll all fire one right after another after three seconds! So rather than using a delay of 3000, we probably want to multiply that by `i` so each character is scheduled for 3000ms after the previous one.

I'd also use `i <= txt.length` rather than hardcoding the number. That way, if you change the text, there's no danger of forgetting to change the number, too.

There's also no need for (but no harm in) the `;` after a function declaration. You need them after *expressions*, not declarations.

So all together:

```
function thanks() {
    $("#writer").text("");
    var txt = "Thanks for visiting !";
    for (var i = 0; i <= txt.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(index) {
            var type = txt.substring(0, index);
            $("#writer").text(type);
        }.bind(null, i), i * 3000);
    };
}
```

`Function#bind` returns a *new* function that, when called, will call the original function with a given `this` value (we don't need that bit, hence the `null` as the first argument) and then whatever arguments we give it (we're passing it `i`, which the function receives as the `index` argument).

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/febumeje/1) *(I used 300 rather than 3000 in the example, 3000 is really widely-spaced)*

Comment: T.J. Crowder, excuse me, but I tried many times. Maybe you didn't updated the new version of your code here, or... something.

Comment: @bonaca: There was an OBOE making the `!` at the end not show in the live example, which I fixed. The code *in* the answer worked without that fix, because it used `< 22` rather than `< str.length` (the correct code is `<= str.length`). BTW, FWIW, while I think this answer is *useful*, I think [Paul's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24368300/157247) is *better*. Doesn't create unnecessary functions.

Comment: T.J. Crowded, I copied your code from the example page and it works, and again copied this code you placed here - doesn't work. Something is different. I will try to check. Anyway, thanks a lot for you efforts and explanations.

Comment: @bonaca: It was poor structuring on my part: You have to take the first code block, but then **also** add the second code block, replacing a line in the first. http://jsbin.com/qocebamo/2 Sorry about that, it really should have been clearer. (I'm off to make it clearer now, for anyone else coming along.)